# DNS Record not found for SubDomain on different Host

Tags: domain, subdomain, dns-zone

My main Domain is hosted on GoDaddy and links to a BigCommerce store. I also have a Wordpress blog on a subdomain that is hosted on BlueHost.

- mysite.com
- blog.mysite.com

Running tests through various online sites (mxtools, intoDNS, etc..), it is reporting that "**DNS Record not found**" for my subdomain.

Following all the guides I've found for this configuration, it seemed the only record I needed to add to GoDaddy was an **A** record pointing the the IP of my BlueHost site. The only records I've added to the BlueHost site were for Zoho email. (MX, spf, dkim, dmarc)  What I don't see on BlueHost is a nameserver record.

Should there be NS records on BlueHost, or should it get resolved by GoDaddy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After speaking with both GoDaddy and BlueHost, it seems no one is certain what, or if anything needs to be done. It's possible that nothing needs to be done after all, but I don't have a clear enough understanding to make that assumption.

The root of this was a query I made on [MXToolBox](https://mxtoolbox.com/). If I queried my root domain, everything looked fine. When I ran my subdomain, I received the error. Here are both queries. Root domain at the top, and subdomain follows.

[mxtoolbox queries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTUZO.jpg)

I can reach my subdomain fine, and an **A** record query on mxtoolbox returns positive, but **MX** & **CNAME** queries return the same "DNS Record not found".

While on hold with GoDaddy I ran across [this article](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/dns/dns-records/dns-cname-record/), and if I understand it correctly, at least the **CNAME** doesn't need to resolve, so I figured the **MX** probably does not either.

Hopefully everything is fine as it is unless someone can tell me otherwise. Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 0):

BlueHost will be able to give you the correct A or CNAME record to use for your subdomain.

You do not need to mess with NS records; these specify where your DNS is hosted.

Comment: I just got off the phone with BlueHost support and they told me I need to speak with GoDaddy to fix the error. Could you be more specific what I need to ask for?

Comment: You need to set your DNS records and perhaps that is with GoDaddy, but only BlueHost can tell you what they are.